# Add row below using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, row, clone

I would like to add row exactly all the same as before, with all the elements as well. Here i have two select options. First, i choose the category, then the product will show up and also i choose product too. After that i choose the quantity, and then the unit price, subtotal, and grandtotal will appear automatically.

Here is the code which i want to duplicate below.

```
<tr style="text-align:center">
    <td>
        <select name="selectCategory" id="selectCategory" class="form-control" style="width: 140px">
           <option value="">-- Category --</option>
 <?php
      $queryCategory = "SELECT * FROM category";
      $sqlCategory = mysql_query($queryCategory);
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlCategory)) {
          echo '<option value="' . $row['category_id'] . '">' . $row['category_name'] . '</option>';
      }
?>
        </select>
     </td>
     <td>
        <select name="selectProduct" id="selectProduct" class="form-control" style="width: 330px">
           <option value="">-- Product --</option>
           <!-- Show the products list -->
        </select>
     </td>
     <td>
         <input type="number" name="txtQty" id="txtQty" class="form-control" value="1" min="1" onchange="calculate()" style="width: 80px; text-align: center"/>
     </td>
     <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtPrice" id="txtPrice" class="form-control" style="text-align:center" readonly/>
     </td>
     <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtTotal" id="txtTotal" class="form-control" style="text-align:center" readonly/>
     </td>
</tr>
```

I was thinking for using jQuery and i found the example, but i didn't understand yet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is not quite clear, can you edit your post to make what you're trying to do easier for us to understand?

Comment: Hi. welcome.. so, you have a two `select` elements. The first one is pre-poluated using PHP. Are there any problems in the first `select` ?

Comment: The second `select` is empty. If im understanding correctly. you want to populate the second `select` depending on what the user selects on the first one correct?

Comment: All : actually i want to attach the image but i couldn't because my reputation less than 10. According to the question. I have 2 select option. First : i choose the category that generated from DB. Then the second select option will show up with the product's name. I choose it too. Then i pick the quantity, and finally the price etc will calculated automatically. So my question is, how to duplicate of those 2 select option, the quantity, etc. ?

Comment: Where should the second `select` get its information from?

Comment: @CodeGodie the first select option is working well, and then the second select already populated. I just wondering, how can i duplicate the full row with all the elements.

Comment: _"duplicate the full row with all elements"_? what do you mean?

Comment: if the product `select` is working, can you provide the HTML for it?

Comment: @CodeGodie im sorry for my english lol. i mean i would to clone the row before exactly all the same. so i can choose the second product nicely. Btw, im doing e-comm website. It is the buy process.

Comment: gotcha.. and no worries, i am a foreigner too lol.. so, I guess the problem is not in the `select` elements.. the problem is that you want to calculate the amounts correct? where are the amounts?... otherwise, what I am understanding when you say 'clone' is that you want to get the exact information from your `select` options and place them somewhere else

Comment: @CodeGodie no dude, the amount, select, is working perfectly. i just need the jquery. So, whenever i clicked the button, so the row shown below the previous row. Actually, i want to doing the buy process which can be accesess many time. So, i really want to know how to add the new row after i clicked the button :) can i email the html to your email maybe? if you dont mind hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want another row below your first one with the information you selected, I would do this:

```
<script>
    $("#selectProduct").change(function() {
        var currentProduct = $(this).val();
        var currentCategory = $("#selectCategory").val();
        var row = "<tr><td>" + currentProduct + "</td><td>" + currentCategory + "</td><td></td><td></td></tr>";
        $("table").append(row);
    });
</script>
```

Now, if you have a button and you want to clone like you mentioned above, i would do something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr class="active_row">
        <td>
            <select name="selectCategory" id="selectCategory" class = "form-control" style = "width: 140px">
                <option value = ""> --Category --</option>
                <!-- your PHP options -->
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="selectProduct" id="selectProduct" class="form-control" style="width: 330px">
                <option value="">-- Product --</option>
                <!-- your PHP options -->
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><!-- quantity info --> </td>
        <td><!-- price info --> </td>
        <td><!-- subtotal info --> </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
$("#add_row_button").click(function(){
    var $row_clone = $(".active_row").clone();
    $(".active_row").addClass("row");
    $(".active_row").removeClass("active_row");
    $("table").append($row_clone);
});
</script>
```